# THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

Подключил Viewer от Autodesk, использующий Three.js. Вьювер с тулбаром работает нормально, а чтобы заработал этот, нужно перезагрузить страницу. Подскажите в чем проблема.
[image: Ошибки]

Подключенные файлы

```html
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=2.10"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/Autodesk360App.js"></script>
```

После перезагрузки страницы все начинает работать.

Ошибка кот в этом коде:

```html
 // Rendering

 this.render = function ( scene, camera, renderTarget, forceClear, customLights ) {

  if ( camera instanceof THREE.Camera === false ) {

   avp.logger.error( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.' );
   return;

  }
```

Comment: Скрипты, в подвале или в шапке?. 
У меня есть сайт с использованием autodesk viewer, могу линкануть и сравните.

Comment: В подвале, если можно, пришлите ссылку

Comment: http://polymetrica.ru/ - примеры работ (значок 3d).

Comment: Пример файла для инициализации слайдера и 3d вида, http://pastebin.com/saGCDKDg

Comment: Дело в том что у Вас другой вьювер. Там есть несколько видов. Тк вот у вас работает вьювер с тулбаром, а проблемы у меня с обычным, который без панели с кнопками.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за вьювер для браузера. Платный/бесплатный, где его найти и есть ли документация.

Comment: До ноября бесплатный. https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/

Comment: Увы, без большей информации не знаю чем еще помочь.
У них очень плохая документация, я имею ввиду js api. 
И хотелось бы уточнить, а где написано про ноябрь? своих хоть предупрежу.

Comment: Могу, еще предложить посмотреть примеры в их группах на гитхабе (я по ним и делал, долго сидел и изучах код - ничего хорошего), https://github.com/developer-autodesk, https://developer-autodesk.github.io/, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/

Comment: http://forge.autodesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Forge_Pricing_Overview.pdf
Распространяется только на загрузку. Просмотривать можно будет бесплатно, так что упасть ничего не должно у вас, только вот заливать новые не получится, если не купите подписку за 600$

Comment: @olegatro Я решил проблему, но очень кривым способом. Стал выводить все вьюверы через фрейм со своего же сайта. Если убрать бордер, то без кода и не заметишь этот костыль.

Comment: @Александр Понял, тогде желаю удачи, ифреймы иногда бывают полезны, мы похожим образом использовали)

Comment: @Александр По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения я вынес весь Viewer на отдельную страницу и вставил его в нужное место как `<iframe frameborder="0" ... >`. Так, без бордеров, никакого отличия от обычного Viewer-а нет и каждый раз он загружается без обновления страницы.